# Not able to call function from React Js Button Click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have Message.js -

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'reactstrap';
class Message extends React.Component
{
    constructor()
    {
super()
this.state={
    message:"This is message"
}
    }
    changeMessage() {
        alert("In");
        this.setState({
            message :"message changed"
        });
    }
    render=()=> {
        return <div>
            <h1>{this.state.message}</h1>
            <Button onClick="{this.changeMessage}" color="success">success</Button>
        </div>
    }
}
export default Message
```

Button click is not working here.
I tried with -

```
<Button onClick={changeMessage} color="success">success</Button>
```

Then Also Tried -

```
<Button onClick="changeMessage()" color="success">success</Button>
```

This also did not work.

[image]

```
Uncaught TypeError : this.props.onClick is not a function.
```

Comment: In your case, you should add the binding function in the constructor just like this.
constructor()   {
   ...
this.changeMessage = this.changeMessage.bind(this)
   ...
} 
or you can define the changeMessage function as the arrow function just like this.
changeMessage = () => {
                .....
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Message extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      message: "This is message",
    };
  }
  changeMessage = () => {
    alert("In");
    this.setState({
      message: "message changed",
    });
  };
  render = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.message}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.changeMessage} color="success">
          success
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  };
}
export default Message;
```

PS: Bhau, as you said you are new to React then I would highly recommend you [Fullstack Open](https://fullstackopen.com/en/#course-contents) part1 - part4, an amazing resource, and very structured.
It will probably take a week to complete and you will learn a lot more than typical Udemy or other tutorial series.

Answer (score 1):

No inverted commas

```
<Button onClick={this.changeMessage} color="success">success</Button>
```

Please bind the function in the constructor or use arrow functions.

Comment: Also changeMessage() { should be changeMessage=()=> { as he is using this.state inside that

Comment: I think he also has to do function binding in the constructor.

Comment: Yes, I am mentioning that too

Comment: @KetanRamteke barobar aahe tumch , mi navin aahe yatt tyamule kahi chuka rahat aahet.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put quotation for functions in reactjs.

Just assign like this.

```
<Button onClick={this.changeMessage} color="success">success</Button>
```

and function

```
changeMessage = () => {
        alert("In");
        this.setState({
            message :"message changed"
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Button onClick={this.changeMessage} color="success">success</Button>

<Button onClick={() => {this.changeMessage(your params)}} color="success">success</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
onClick={this.changeMessage} need not to be a string .
```

Try this :

```
<Button onClick={()=>this.changeMessage()} color="success">success</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The onClick you passed should be a function and the function has to be bound to use "**this**" pointer inside the "**changeMessage**" function, so you can try using as follows,

```
<Button onClick={this.changeMessage.bind(this)} color="success">success</Button>
```